# Перемещать кнопку к элементу, по которому кликнули

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть несколько блоков в форме, мне нужно по клику на блок перемещать в него кнопку. Нужно чтобы кнопка перемещалась к каждому label в пределах своего родителя .check

Вот пример:

```css
.check {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.check label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-1">
                <input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                <span>Motul</span>
               </label>
  <label for="check-2">
                <input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                <span>Motul</span>
               </label>
  <label for="check-3">
                <input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                <span>Motul</span>
               </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>

<div class="check">
  <label for="check-4">
                <input id="check-4" class="element-checkbox" name="check-4" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                <span>Motul</span>
               </label>
  <label for="check-5">
                <input id="check-5" class="element-checkbox" name="check-5" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                <span>Motul</span>
               </label>
  <label for="check-6">
                <input id="check-6" class="element-checkbox" name="check-6" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                <span>Motul</span>
               </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(".check label").click(function() {
  $('.box-button').appendTo(this);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) - ищем родителя

[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) - ищем нужный элемент внутри родителя

```js
$(".check label").click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.check').find('.box-button').appendTo(this);
});
```

```css
.check {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.check label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-1">
  <input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
  <span>Motul</span>
 </label>
  <label for="check-2">
  <input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
  <span>Motul</span>
 </label>
  <label for="check-3">
  <input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
  <span>Motul</span>
 </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>
<div class="check">
  <label for="check-4">
  <input id="check-4" class="element-checkbox" name="check-4" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
  <span>Motul</span>
 </label>
  <label for="check-5">
  <input id="check-5" class="element-checkbox" name="check-5" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
  <span>Motul</span>
 </label>
  <label for="check-6">
  <input id="check-6" class="element-checkbox" name="check-6" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
  <span>Motul</span>
 </label>
  <button class="box-button">Показать</button>
</div>
```